# Control activated webservices

Tags: python, django, web-services

i'm new in all of webservices and more webservices with python.

I tested bottle, ladon, flask and django REST framework... With different opinions but all working more or less fine. Now i need to have something like a admin view to start or stop these services. Looking these frameworks i cant find anything about it.
I searched here and neither.

So i was looking for something like admin django view where i can start o stop a service. Which framework or technology do you recommend me?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a webserver (Apache, nginx...) before that. Depending on the webserver and OS it can be rather easy to deactivate a site. For example Ubuntu + Apache

- configure a default host that returns only `503 Service Unavailable`
- configure a site configuration with a VirtualHost with the actual WSGI setup for the webservice
- activate the website with `a2ensite <name>` and `service apache2 reload`
- activate the website with `a2dissite <name>` and `service apache2 reload`

But there are very many other solutions to your problem.

Comment: Maybe i explain myself bad. I was talking about ubuntu+apache+wsgi, for that i ask for a framework that make this work easly.